# WooCommerce conditional tag for particular product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[WooCommerce Conditional Tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/) page suggests that we can find when a product page is running,

but unlike `is_single` it does not accepts any parameter to go for any specific product name or slug.

I want to run a script only for a specific product suppose,

http://localhost/realtour/product/demo-tour-package/

I want to run a script on init action hook and check for a specific product. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Where or in what script you need to target a specific product? this question is unclear as it is…

Answer (score 2):

`is_product` is simply a wrapper to `is_singular('product')`

To check for specific product, you need to check for either ID or permalink.

```
if (is_product()) {

    if (basename(get_permalink()) == 'demo-tour-package') {

        # ...
    }
}
```